# Ignoring all security/privacy risks, what can I do to increase my internet speed?

Tags: internet

Let's say I don't care about my security/privacy/ANYTHING besides speed. How can I increase my internet speeds?

Comment: Plug your computer directly into the modem, and you'll get the highest speed your ISP is giving you. Other than that, you'd need to pay for a faster plan. You can't make your Internet faster than your ISP provides it to you.

Comment: Although this isn't actually likely to make a difference unless the connection is really really fast or the router is particularly awful. Even an ancient router can handle a typical residential <10Mbps connection. (But if you do have a very fast connection, the solution is to get a better router, not to plug your PC into the modem.)

Comment: Anyway, what to do depends on what you're doing. Web browsing, try to disable JS/images (sites won't look great, but they'll load a lot faster). Torrents, use the appropriate NAT settings, make sure your equipment can handle lots of parallel connections and cap your upload appropriately (or use your modem's "Turbo TCP" feature or equivalent). Streaming, use your router's QoS settings appropriately. And so forth.

Comment: You can live next to the phone exchange in the hope of better ADSL speed... (but you are and will still be capped by your ISP)

Comment: @user55325 I have 100MBps down, 20 up from comcast and usually get around 60 down/7 up. I don't need any faster speeds, but I was just wondering.

Comment: That is a very fast connection and with the right hardware you could probably get better speeds. I don't know much about consumer-grade routers, but in that situation I would probably get a small-form-factor PC (or any reasonably decent machine will work), add a couple of gigabit NICs, and install pfSense on it. You can plug a gigabit switch into that if you want more ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options, except for the first few, most of them are not very practical.

1. Pay for faster internet from your ISP and call it good.
2. Take your laptop to the library
3. Connect your computer to the router with an ethernet cable, don't use wifi.
4. If latency is your enemy, buy a network card designed for low latency http://www.killergaming.com/solutions/Network_Cards
5. Mod your cable modem to trick the cable company into giving you faster internet (illegal and unethical, don't do it).
6. Get two internet connections, setup a load balancer such as pfsense, untangled, or purchase two dedicated load balancers.
7. Move to Kansas City, Austin Texas or Provo Utah so you can get google fiber https://fiber.google.com/cities/

Any other tips like turning off your firewall will give you such negligible improvements, it wouldn't be worth it.

Comment: Just curious, is number five really illegal if I own my own modem? I have no plans to do it (I have super fast internet already) I'm just wondering.

Comment: If you consume more bandwidth then you pay for, it would be considered stealing. There are reports of people arrested for selling modded cable modems http://www.techspot.com/news/49195-hacker-gets-three-years-in-prison-for-selling-rooted-cable-modems.html